# Download Windows XP Professional

Tags: windows-xp

How or where do I download **Windows XP Professional (English)  (32 Bit)** ?   -  I have a product key.

As I seen in google search Microsoft release some ISO for Windows (like [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/c0e78d7a-883d-4caa-a8c0-1e127a14612a/)) but I didn't find any link for the version I need   .

Direct link would be welcome  .

Answer (score 2):

There are several Microsoft repositories that would allow you to download XP versions:

1. MSDN - requires subscription
2. TechNet - requires subscription
3. BizSiteSpark - is free, but you need to be a business owner

Comment: at MSDN and TechNet  I just found SP3 for XP pro  , can you give direct link please ?

Comment: I just looked and I see several versions of XP, Pro and Home, 32 and 64bit with SP3. I can't paste a link, as they use their download controls - they are all on the same MSDN page. Sorry. Maybe you need to have a certain level of MSDN to see it?